# How can I get a table, logarithmic in x but line in y?

Tags: list-manipulation, logarithmic-scale

The code is like:

```
f[x_,y_]:=x^2+y^2;
Table[f[x,y],{x,{10^Range[-3,2]}},{y,0,1,1}];
```

The table is not working now. It shows:

```
The second part of {} doesn't exist.
```

Comment: @cvgmt Sorry,but this can't work.... I type this wrong... Your version can't work,too.

Comment: The code in your question already works fine. Have you tried removing the semicolon at the end of the Table statement? That will show you the output. If that output is not what you want, then please give an example of an acceptable result as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Range[]` returns a list, so you shouldn't wrap it in `{}`:

```
f[x_,y_]:=x^2+y^2;
Table[f[x,y],{x,10^Range[-3,2]},{y,0,1,1}];
```

You can also adjust increments if you need more number in-between, for example:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;
TableForm[
 Flatten[
  Table[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {x, 10^Range[-3, 2, 0.5]}, {y, 0, 1, 0.5}]
  , 1]
 , TableHeadings -> {None, {"x", "y", "f[x,y]"}}]
```

[image]